# Can I use Define in Oracle SQL reports?

Tags: sql, oracle

First I want to state that I'm new to Oracle SQL and doesn't have too much experience in coding.

I'm creating a report for our finance department and I have multiple formulas for counting PO amounts, invoiced amounts, received amounts etc. I would like to define those formulas as variables so I don't have write the formulas every time I use them in code. What I need to know is that does defining a variable somehow do changes to original DB table?

Example case from my code:

```
SELECT
(t.arrived_qty * t.buy_unit_price)*((100-a.discount)/100)+i.additional_cost
```

For example I would like to define arrived qty multiplied with buy unit price as Received amount

```
DEF received_qty = t.arrived_qty * t.buy_unit_price

SELECT &received_qty
```

Can this sort of logic be used in self service reports or does this modify the original DB table somehow?

Hopefully I was able to explain myself clear enough

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do that and it will not change any DB tables (DDL or DML)

See the example of using the expression as a variable:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT;

    ACC_NR       SUM_    CUST_ID     SALARY
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       500       3400        100
       600       5000        101
       700       5070        102

SQL>
SQL> -- Defining the TOT as CUST_ID + SUM_
SQL>
SQL> DEF TOT = CUST_ID + SUM_;
SQL>
SQL> -- Selecting data using the above formula (variable)
SQL>
SQL> SELECT ACC_NR, &TOT AS TOTAL FROM ACCOUNT;
old   1: SELECT ACC_NR, &TOT AS TOTAL FROM ACCOUNT
new   1: SELECT ACC_NR, CUST_ID AS TOTAL FROM ACCOUNT

    ACC_NR      TOTAL
---------- ----------
       500        100
       600        101
       700        102

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! I will try that